# CPython compiled failed in macOS

Tags: python, macos, compiler-errors

version: `macOS 10.14.4`, `Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)`.

I cloned the CPython source code from GitHub then compiled it which used to work quite well. However, I messed up my terminal a few days ago for installing gdb. Now when I try to compile the CPython source code with `./configure --with-pydebug && make -j` I always get the error messages:

```
ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file libpython3.8d.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): libpython3.8d.aignoring file libpython3.8d.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): libpython3.8d.a

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__Py_UnixMain", referenced from:
      _main in python.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyEval_InitThreads", referenced from:
      _test_repeated_init_and_subinterpreters in _testembed.o
  "_PyEval_ReleaseThread", referenced from:
      _test_repeated_init_and_subinterpreters in _testembed.o
  "_PyEval_RestoreThread", referenced from:
      _test_repeated_init_and_subinterpreters in _testembed.o
      _test_bpo20891 in _testembed.o
  "_PyEval_SaveThread", referenced from:
      _test_bpo20891 in _testembed.o
  "_PyGILState_Check", referenced from:
      _bpo20891_thread in _testembed.o
  "_PyGILState_Ensure", referenced from:
      _test_repeated_init_and_subinterpreters in _testembed.o
      _bpo20891_thread in _testembed.o
  "_PyGILState_Release", referenced from:
      _test_repeated_init_and_subinterpreters in _testembed.o
      _bpo20891_thread in _testembed.o
  "_PyInterpreterState_GetID", referenced from:
      _print_subinterp in _testembed.o
  "_PyMem_RawFree", referenced from:
      _test_pre_initialization_api in _testembed.o
  "_PyRun_SimpleStringFlags", referenced from:
      _test_pre_initialization_api in _testembed.o
      _test_pre_initialization_sys_options in _testembed.o
      _test_init_main in _testembed.o
      _check_stdio_details in _testembed.o
      _print_subinterp in _testembed.o
      _dump_config in _testembed.o
  "_PySys_AddWarnOption", referenced from:
      _test_pre_initialization_sys_options in _testembed.o
  "_PySys_AddXOption", referenced from:
      _test_pre_initialization_sys_options in _testembed.o
  "_PySys_ResetWarnOptions", referenced from:
      _test_pre_initialization_sys_options in _testembed.o
  "_PyThreadState_Get", referenced from:
      _test_repeated_init_and_subinterpreters in _testembed.o
      _print_subinterp in _testembed.o
  "_PyThreadState_Swap", referenced from:
      _test_repeated_init_and_subinterpreters in _testembed.o
  "_PyThread_acquire_lock", referenced from:
      _test_bpo20891 in _testembed.o
  "_PyThread_allocate_lock", referenced from:
      _test_bpo20891 in _testembed.o
  "_PyThread_exit_thread", referenced from:
      _bpo20891_thread in _testembed.o
  "_PyThread_free_lock", referenced from:
      _test_bpo20891 in _testembed.o
  "_PyThread_release_lock", referenced from:
      _bpo20891_thread in _testembed.o
  "_PyThread_start_new_thread", referenced from:
      _test_bpo20891 in _testembed.o
  "_Py_BytesWarningFlag", referenced from:
      _test_init_global_config in _testembed.o
      _test_init_from_config in _testembed.o
      _set_all_global_config_variables in _testembed.o
  "_Py_DebugFlag", referenced from:
      _set_all_global_config_variables in _testembed.o
  "_Py_DecodeLocale", referenced from:
      _test_pre_initialization_api in _testembed.o
  "_Py_DontWriteBytecodeFlag", referenced from:
      _test_init_global_config in _testembed.o
      _test_init_from_config in _testembed.o
      _set_all_global_config_variables in _testembed.o
      _check_init_python_config in _testembed.o
  "_Py_EndInterpreter", referenced from:
      _test_repeated_init_and_subinterpreters in _testembed.o
  "_Py_Finalize", referenced from:
      _test_forced_io_encoding in _testembed.o
      _test_repeated_init_and_subinterpreters in _testembed.o
      _test_pre_initialization_api in _testembed.o
      _test_pre_initialization_sys_options in _testembed.o
      _test_initialize_twice in _testembed.o
      _test_initialize_pymain in _testembed.o
      _test_init_default_config in _testembed.o
      ...
  "_Py_FrozenFlag", referenced from:
      _test_init_global_config in _testembed.o
      _test_init_from_config in _testembed.o
      _set_all_global_config_variables in _testembed.o
      _check_init_python_config in _testembed.o
  "_Py_IgnoreEnvironmentFlag", referenced from:
      _test_init_env in _testembed.o
      _test_init_env_dev_mode in _testembed.o
      _test_init_env_dev_mode_alloc in _testembed.o
      _set_all_global_config_variables in _testembed.o
      _check_init_python_config in _testembed.o
  "_Py_Initialize", referenced from:
      _test_forced_io_encoding in _testembed.o
      _test_pre_initialization_api in _testembed.o
      _test_initialize_twice in _testembed.o
      _test_init_global_config in _testembed.o
      __testembed_Py_Initialize in _testembed.o
  "_Py_InspectFlag", referenced from:
      _test_init_global_config in _testembed.o
      _test_init_from_config in _testembed.o
      _set_all_global_config_variables in _testembed.o
  "_Py_InteractiveFlag", referenced from:
      _test_init_global_config in _testembed.o
      _test_init_from_config in _testembed.o
      _set_all_global_config_variables in _testembed.o
  "_Py_IsolatedFlag", referenced from:
      _test_init_isolated_flag in _testembed.o
      _test_preinit_isolated2 in _testembed.o
      _set_all_global_config_variables in _testembed.o
      _check_init_python_config in _testembed.o
  "_Py_Main", referenced from:
      _test_initialize_pymain in _testembed.o
  "_Py_NewInterpreter", referenced from:
      _test_repeated_init_and_subinterpreters in _testembed.o
  "_Py_NoSiteFlag", referenced from:
      _test_init_global_config in _testembed.o
      _test_init_from_config in _testembed.o
      _set_all_global_config_variables in _testembed.o
      _check_init_python_config in _testembed.o
  "_Py_NoUserSiteDirectory", referenced from:
      _test_init_global_config in _testembed.o
      _test_init_from_config in _testembed.o
      _set_all_global_config_variables in _testembed.o
      _check_init_python_config in _testembed.o
  "_Py_OptimizeFlag", referenced from:
      _test_init_global_config in _testembed.o
      _test_init_from_config in _testembed.o
      _set_all_global_config_variables in _testembed.o
  "_Py_QuietFlag", referenced from:
      _test_init_global_config in _testembed.o
      _test_init_from_config in _testembed.o
      _set_all_global_config_variables in _testembed.o
  "_Py_SetProgramName", referenced from:
      _test_pre_initialization_api in _testembed.o
      _test_init_global_config in _testembed.o
      _test_init_from_config in _testembed.o
      __testembed_Py_Initialize in _testembed.o
  "_Py_SetStandardStreamEncoding", referenced from:
      _test_forced_io_encoding in _testembed.o
      _test_init_from_config in _testembed.o
      _check_stdio_details in _testembed.o
  "_Py_UTF8Mode", referenced from:
      _test_init_global_config in _testembed.o
      _test_init_from_config in _testembed.o
  "_Py_UnbufferedStdioFlag", referenced from:
      _test_init_global_config in _testembed.o
      _test_init_from_config in _testembed.o
      _set_all_global_config_variables in _testembed.o
      _check_init_python_config in _testembed.o
  "_Py_VerboseFlag", referenced from:
      _test_init_global_config in _testembed.o
      _test_init_from_config in _testembed.o
      _set_all_global_config_variables in _testembed.o
  "__PyCoreConfig_Clear", referenced from:
      _test_preinit_parse_argv in _testembed.o
      _test_preinit_dont_parse_argv in _testembed.o
      _test_init_read_set in _testembed.o
      _test_run_main in _testembed.o
  "__PyCoreConfig_DecodeLocale", referenced from:
      _test_init_read_set in _testembed.o
  "__PyCoreConfig_Init", referenced from:
      _test_init_from_config in _testembed.o
      _test_preinit_isolated1 in _testembed.o
      _test_preinit_isolated2 in _testembed.o
  "__PyCoreConfig_InitIsolatedConfig", referenced from:
      _test_preinit_dont_parse_argv in _testembed.o
      _check_preinit_isolated_config in _testembed.o
  "__PyCoreConfig_InitPythonConfig", referenced from:
      _test_init_dont_configure_locale in _testembed.o
      _test_init_dev_mode in _testembed.o
      _test_init_isolated_flag in _testembed.o
      _test_preinit_parse_argv in _testembed.o
      _test_init_read_set in _testembed.o
      _test_init_run_main in _testembed.o
      _test_init_main in _testembed.o
      ...
  "__PyCoreConfig_Read", referenced from:
      _test_init_read_set in _testembed.o
  "__PyCoreConfig_SetString", referenced from:
      _test_preinit_parse_argv in _testembed.o
      _test_preinit_dont_parse_argv in _testembed.o
      _test_init_read_set in _testembed.o
      _test_run_main in _testembed.o
  "__PyCoreConfig_SetWideArgv", referenced from:
      _test_preinit_parse_argv in _testembed.o
      _test_preinit_dont_parse_argv in _testembed.o
      _test_run_main in _testembed.o
  "__PyInitError_Failed", referenced from:
      _test_init_from_config in _testembed.o
      _test_init_dont_configure_locale in _testembed.o
      _test_init_dev_mode in _testembed.o
      _test_init_isolated_flag in _testembed.o
      _test_preinit_isolated1 in _testembed.o
      _test_preinit_isolated2 in _testembed.o
      _test_preinit_parse_argv in _testembed.o
      ...
  "__PyInitError_NoMemory", referenced from:
      _test_init_read_set in _testembed.o
  "__PyPreConfig_Init", referenced from:
      _test_init_from_config in _testembed.o
      _test_preinit_isolated1 in _testembed.o
      _test_preinit_isolated2 in _testembed.o
  "__PyPreConfig_InitIsolatedConfig", referenced from:
      _test_preinit_dont_parse_argv in _testembed.o
      _check_preinit_isolated_config in _testembed.o
  "__PyPreConfig_InitPythonConfig", referenced from:
      _test_init_dont_configure_locale in _testembed.o
      _check_init_python_config in _testembed.o
  "__PyRuntime", referenced from:
      _check_preinit_isolated_config in _testembed.o
  "__PyWstrList_Append", referenced from:
      _test_init_read_set in _testembed.o
  "__Py_ExitInitError", referenced from:
      _test_init_from_config in _testembed.o
      _test_init_dont_configure_locale in _testembed.o
      _test_init_dev_mode in _testembed.o
      _test_init_isolated_flag in _testembed.o
      _test_preinit_isolated1 in _testembed.o
      _test_preinit_isolated2 in _testembed.o
      _test_preinit_parse_argv in _testembed.o
      ...
  "__Py_InitializeFromConfig", referenced from:
      _test_init_from_config in _testembed.o
      _test_init_dont_configure_locale in _testembed.o
      _test_init_dev_mode in _testembed.o
      _test_init_isolated_flag in _testembed.o
      _test_preinit_isolated1 in _testembed.o
      _test_preinit_isolated2 in _testembed.o
      _test_preinit_parse_argv in _testembed.o
      ...
  "__Py_InitializeMain", referenced from:
      _test_init_main in _testembed.o
  "__Py_PreInitialize", referenced from:
      _test_init_from_config in _testembed.o
      _test_init_dont_configure_locale in _testembed.o
      _test_preinit_isolated1 in _testembed.o
      _test_preinit_isolated2 in _testembed.o
      _check_preinit_isolated_config in _testembed.o
      _check_init_python_config in _testembed.o
  "__Py_PreInitializeFromWideArgs", referenced from:
      _test_preinit_dont_parse_argv in _testembed.o
  "__Py_RunMain", referenced from:
      _test_init_run_main in _testembed.o
      _test_init_main in _testembed.o
      _test_run_main in _testembed.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clangclang: : errorerror: : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

make: *** [Programs/_testembed] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [python.exe] Error 1
```

I tried run `make distclean` and reset my terminal but still not working. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Inada from python-list, I found a [post about it](https://naoyat.hatenablog.jp/entry/2012/01/31/033312), it looks like for some reason the `ar` and `ranlib` didn't work as expected. I created some soft links for  these tools:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/ranlib /usr/local/bin/ranlib

ln -s /usr/bin/ar /usr/local/bin/ar
```

Then everything works as expected.